# Kafka stream aggregate

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a problem with a kafka stream aggregate.

What I would like to have is that for every input data that arrives on the input topic, we have a new version of the output aggregation KTable that is produced and then joined to a second topic.

In reality, we don't have that 1:1...so we don't do enough joining with the second topic and we miss processing.

I'm sure the problem is with the aggregations because I wrote the output of the aggregation in a topic, which I put a consumer on: I do observe that I don't have enough versions of the KTable being produced.

We found some settings to improve things: by playing with the COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG and CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG parameters of the Kafka stream configuration, we have a better processing rate.

Is playing with these parameters the right solution to make the aggregate method produce a version of the aggregation KTable systematically? If so, what value should be set?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Here is the code of the aggregation and the joinning :

```
KGroupedStream<String, GenericRecord> groupedEventStream = eventsSource.groupByKey();
KStream<String, String> resultStream =
        groupedEventStream.aggregate(this::initSensorAggregatedRecord, this::updateSensorAggregatedRecord).leftJoin(secondSource,
            this::bindSecondSource).toStream();
```

Here is the settings we have set on the kafka stream configuration :

```
props.put(COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 0);
props.put(CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);
```

Regards
CG

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a new window for each incoming record you should use the sliding windows [sliding windows](https://kafka.apache.org/27/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/SlidingWindows.html). They are not exactly what you are looking for but you can adjust the windowing time you might get it to work for you.